# How to convert an array of string to a sentence?

Tags: c#

How can I use Linq query methods to convert an array of string to a sentence?

```
private static void Main()
{
    string sentence = "C# is fun.";
    string[] words = sentence.Split();
    //string temp= words;       
}
```

The `temp` wants to have the same value as `sentence`.

Comment: What has to do LINQ here?

Comment: @rendon: Just for learning LINQ.

Comment: `String.Join` is a better option here. Don't use LINQ just to use LINQ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```
var temp = words.Aggregate((x, y) => x + " " + y);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```
var res = string.Join(" ", words);
```

or

```
string[] words = { "one", "two", "three" };
var res = words.Aggregate((current, next) => current + " " + next);
```

Comment: why, why, why `words.ToArray` ? it is already an array what's the point? even if it isn't, string.Join takes `IEnumerable<T>` as parameter,so you don't need to convert it to a list or array.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [**String.Join**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
private static void Main()
{
    string sentence = "C# is fun.";
    string[] words = sentence.Split();

    // Join the words back together, with a " " in between each one.
    string temp = String.Join(" ", words);
}
```

Comment: The only answer here which provides an example that should be used in real code.

Answer (score 3):

```
string temp = words.Aggregate((workingSentence, next) => 
      workingSentence + " " + next);
```

ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651%28v=vs.110%29.aspx